# Expected equal JSON strings are not equal when compared using assertEquals

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, junit, equality

I wrote JUnit test for the web service client, which submits JSON document to the service.

I saved "correct" JSON document to the file, then after the test execution I compare it with actual result.

They are not matched, although lines are identical:

```
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
    Expected :{"Callback":null,"Data":
    {"MarketCode":"ISEM",,............"Price":2.99}]}]}]}]}}
    Actual   :{"Callback":null,"Data":
    {"MarketCode":"ISEM",,............"Price":2.99}]}]}]}]}}
```

Lines are very long , about 4K characters, so I cut much of it here, but their length is identical. I compared string.size() in the debugger , and also I trim it before the compare, to remove some invisible or whitespace symbols in the end, which text editor can implicitly insert.

Also, test is OK when executed isolately. But it fails , when I run it as part of bigger suite.

There is no global/static variables, so memory overriding should be not an issue.
I'm mocking web service client to extract the request string , like this:

```
StringBuilder pd = new StringBuilder();
doAnswer((invocation) -> {
  String postDocument = ((String)invocation.getArguments()[0]).trim();
  pd.append(postDocument);
  return null;
}).when(client).doPost(anyString(), anyObject());
```

client is mocked class.

Then I compare trimmed versions of strings, but it doesnt help

```
String expectedSubmit = TestUtils.readXmlFromFile("strategyexecution\\ireland_bm_strategy_override_expected.json").trim();
assertEquals(expectedSubmit, pd.toString().trim());
```

Comment: Can it be an encoding problem? You could try to write both string to separate files and take and md5 or sha1 checksum to see if the actual bytes are the same.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] `assertEquals` is not broken

Comment: Runs fine on Jenkins env. looks like bug in IntelliJ IDEA.  it fails only in IDEA and only when the whole suite (not isolated test in one class file) executed

Answer (score 1):

I found answer myself :-)
The problem is with JSON specification itself.
JSON cannot guarantee the same order of elements inside the array, it's basically unordered set.
So, the content can be randomly reordered. Two produced JSON files should not be compared as two strings.

I deserialized it to Java object and object comparision works!

Answer (score 1):

Same old issue as we had with XML. For XML there is [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/) which *semantically* compares xml-s. For JSON I'd try to use a similar tool, like [JsoNunit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit). [JSONAssert](http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/) too looks promising.